# semantics for quantifier FOL

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have a doubt regarding an intuition with respect to the way we evaluate quantified formulas:

The truth condition for a quantified formula ∀xF are:

$v(M,g)$ assign T to $∀xF$ iff for every d in the domain of $M$, $v(M,g[x/d])$ assign T to F.

Can't we just write:

$v(M,g)$ assign T to $∀xF$ iff for every element d in the domain, if this element is assigned to x, F is true.

This is the same as saying that:

$v(M,g)$ assign T to ∀xF iff for every element d, there exists an assignment function j such that $j(x)=d$ and $v(M,j)$ makes F true.

Why should we introduce a $g$-variant assignment when we can refer to an arbitray assignment $j$ not related to $g$?

Answer (score 2):

The first definition you state is the correct one. Your idea involving the assignments $j$ is not equivalent to it.

Consider for example $M=(\mathbb{N}, \geq)$ with $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,...\}$. Let $g$ be the assignment $g(x)=1$, $g(y)=1$. According to the given definition, the formula $\forall x(x\geq y)$ is false in $(M,g)$. Just consider $g[x/0]$. However, for each $d \in \mathbb{N}$ we can find an assignment $j$ which sends $x$ to $d$ such that $(M,j)$ makes it true: Choose $j(x)=d$ and $j(y)=0$.

**Edit (in response to the comments):** The real reason behind the usage of those "$g$-variants" $g[x/d]$ for the quantified case is to correctly express dependencies between variables in statements of the form $\exists x \forall yF$ or $\forall x \exists yF$. For example, using the correct definition with "$g$-variants", you will find out that the statement

$\phantom{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}$"$v(M,g)$ assigns T to the formula $\exists x \forall y(x≥y)$"

exactly means that there is at least one element $x \in M$ greater or equal than any $y \in M$. This is what we want. However, your proposal where we can use arbitrary assignments $j$ not related to the original one won't work. For example, your proposal would make the formula $\exists x \forall y(x≥y)$ true in $(\mathbb{N},\geq)$ (under any assignment) which we certainly don't want.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it. I still do not get why we should introduce a g-variable function relative to the initial function chosen for the valuation. Is there a reason why we define it in this way?                                                                                "The key point is that in ∀-case, it is important that the assignment is the same as g except that that it assigns d to x " what I do not get is why is it important that we chose exactly the g-variant as the "new" assignment.

Comment: This is done to correctly express dependencies between variables in statements of the form $\exists x \forall y F$ or $\forall x \exists y F$. For example, using the correct definition with "$g$-variants", you will find out that "$\exists x \forall y(x \geq y)$ is true in $(M,g)$" exactly means that there is at least one element $x \in M$ greater or equal than any $y \in M$. This is what we want.

Comment: If you avoid the $g$-variants and just use arbitrary assignments in the quantified case, a formula like $\exists x \forall y(x \geq y)$ would not have the intended meaning. It would for example be true in $(\mathbb{N}, \geq)$ which we don't want.

Comment: The only reason for adopting the decision with g variant is just due to the problem you've mentioned in the answer?

Comment: In the posted answer, I only explain that your version is not equivalent to the correct version with the "$g$-variants". In the two comments, I tried to explain what the real idea behind this is (and also why your version won't work).

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. So, the problem only arise when we consider formulas with multiple quantifiers?

Comment: So to say yes. As I explained in the comments, those $g$-variants are necessary to express the dependencies between variables in a correct way. Maybe I edit my answer add the comments there.

Comment: Ok thanks. The thing was not clear to me because I could not see the justification behind the choice of the g-variant and I thought the same could be done by any assignment function